# 'find exec' once with all found names as arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, find

Short question is: how to call some command or a script once with all found names as arguments plus some extra arguments?

Long question is:

Why does this work (prints all file names 1 name per line):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;
```

but this doesn't (prints nothing):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "echo {}" +
```

However, this works (prints all file names in a line):

```
find . -type f -exec echo {} +
```

but this fails with message `find: missing argument to '-exec'` :

```
find . -type f -exec echo {} more args +
```

However, this prints file names but not `more args`:

```
find . -type f -exec echo '{} more args' +
```

(prints `./file1.txt ./file2.txt` while I expected `./file1.txt ./file2.txt more args`)

I know there is a limit on how long the argument list can be, but I tested it with just a few file names so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Try either `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"' sh {} \;` or `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh {} +`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Seems to work, though I don't understand it. What does the second `sh` do?

Comment: Sets `$0` for `sh`.

Comment: So the answer is that it HAS to end with a `{} +` and I can't put the `{}` anywhere else, even inside quotes?

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't put `{}` inside quotes.

Comment: `-exec echo '{} more args' +` -- that looks like a bug in GNU find, [the standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) that "Only a <plus-sign> that immediately follows an argument containing only the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression." and the string there contains more than just the `{}` so it shouldn't be taken as part of the `{} +` construct, and find should complain about the separator being missing